# Проблема с простым объектом и расчетом

Tags: javascript

Выдает

> `undefined`

Нужно, чтобы все значения в `payroll` суммировались и вывелись. Спасибо!

```
let payroll = {
    Jack: 2000,
    Alex: 3000,
    Mary: 1594,
    David: 'nextweek'
};

function calcAddedPayroll(obj) {
    for(let key in obj){
        if(typeof obj[key] == 'number'){
            obj[key]+obj[key]
        }
    }
}

alert(calcAddedPayroll(payroll));
```

Comment: и куда оно у вас суммируется?)) в какую переменную? а функция должна что-то возвращать, как вы считаете?

Comment: undefined - потому что вы не возвращаете ничего из фукнции. Так же в самой фукнции сумму надо присваивать какой то переменной и уже ее возвращать

Comment: всем спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let payroll = {
  Jack: 2000,
  Alex: 3000,
  Mary: 1594,
  David: 'nextweek'
};

function calcAddedPayroll(obj) {
  let a = 0;
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'number') {
      a += obj[key];
    }
  }
  return a
}

console.log(calcAddedPayroll(payroll));
```

можно так